# Weird sharedPreference issue with my Android app

Tags: android, android-studio, sharedpreferences

The issue is the default value set to SharedPreferences is changing depending on whether I install the app from Google Play store or install the apk directly (or clear storage of the app after installing from Play store).

Installing from Play store I get my Boolean value as false.

Clearing storage and running again, I get my Boolean value as true.

```
private void setShowStoragePermission(boolean permission){
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences  = getSharedPreferences("storagePermission", MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putBoolean("permission", permission).apply();
}

private boolean getShowStoragePermission(){
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences  = getSharedPreferences("storagePermission", MODE_PRIVATE);
    return sharedPreferences.getBoolean("permission", true);
}
```

On first clean run, there are no saved SharedPreferences so the value returned by
getShowStoragePermission() returns true. But, I am getting false when installing from the Play store as seen by the toast in the first few seconds ("savedPermission: false");

You can see it yourself on the **Beta version** of the app:
[Link to app on Play store](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.rroycsdev.bingtools)
//

I am testing the app on Android P DP4. Any solutions to this problem?

Code in MainActivity:

```
if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        setToast("savedPermission: " + getShowStoragePermission(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        //on first run from Google Play store @getShowStoragePermission returns false - need to return true
        if(getShowStoragePermission()) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                    MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
        } else {
            makeBingWallRequest(false);
        }
    }else{
        //storage permission granted manually from app settings or from dialog request
        createImageDir();
        makeBingWallRequest(true);
    }
```

Where SharedPreferences is set:

```
    private void makeBingWallRequest(boolean storagePermission){
    if(getDeviceInternetStatus(context) == null && getBingWallDay() == 0){
        bingImage.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.bearcats));
        return;
    }
    if(!storagePermission){
       new BingWallpaper(MainActivity.this).execute(false);
    }else {
        Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getDefault());
        int day = now.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        //on first run
        setToast("savedBingWallDay: " + getBingWallDay(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        if(getBingWallDay() == FIRST_RUN_BING_IMAGE){
            saveBingWallDay();
            new BingWallpaper(MainActivity.this).execute(true);
            //every other run
        }else if (day != getBingWallDay()) {
           //if current time is past 3AM then make new request
            int hourIn24 = now.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
            if(hourIn24 >= BING_IMAGE_RESET_HOUR_IN_24){
                saveBingWallDay();
                new BingWallpaper(MainActivity.this).execute(true);
            }else loadBitmap();
        } else loadBitmap();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the code that calls both functions from your activity/fragment.

Comment: can you also check on different devices with a different version? It will help us to investigate more.

Comment: I have updated the post with calls to both functions in my activity. Going to test on another device soon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had similar symptoms, only to later find out it was the **autobackup** feature (introduced with Android 6). Uninstalling doesn't clear that data, since it's fetched from Google's cloud (simply your Google Drive).

Read more: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/autobackup

To test this simply disable the backup feature, and repeat the tests to make sure you get the expected default values. Set `android:allowBackup` to `false`:

```
<manifest ... >
    ...
    <application android:allowBackup="false" ... >
        ...
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Also, I can not but urge you not to store permission states on the local disk. Why not call `Context.checkCallingOrSelfPermission()` in runtime? it is the safer way.

Comment: Thanks, that solved the problem. I am not sure how to use Context.checkCallingOrSelfPermission(). If I use Context.checkSelfPermission() and user denies the permission, my code above keeps asking user for permission until I get permission granted. I am not sure how else I can prevent that without storing the state in SharedPreferences.

Comment: @rated2016 The general idea should be something like this:
`if (anyContext.checkCallingOrSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
 Log.d(TAG, "Our app needs a missing permission, will now ask for it");
 activityContext.requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 123);
}`

To avoid hammering the user with permission requests you should design an "onboarding process" where you ask for permissions only in a flow where you first "convince the user" as to why she would grant you these permissions...